# How is a "conformal latitude" used in ellipsoidal stereographic projections?

Tags: coordinate-system, datum

At my work, I've been doing some maintenance on internal software that claims to implement a Stereographic projection whose formulas were copied from an old system a long time ago.

From what I've seen, it seems to implement the "Oblique and Equatorial Stereographic" from EPSG (code 9809). But there is one step that I was not able to identify. The "R" value used in our code is calculated with the following parameters:

```
(phi_n, lambda_n) - null distortion coordinates
(PHI_nc, LAMBDA_nc) - conformal null distortion coordinates
(PHI_o, LAMBDA_o) - conformal projection origin coordinates
e - eccenttricity
r_eq - earth radius at equator
```

Given this, the formula to get R is:

```
a = 1 + cos(PHI_nc) * cos(PHI_o) * cos(LAMBDA_nc - LAMBA_o)
b = sin(PHI_nc) * sin(PHI_o) 
c = 2 * cos(PHI_nc) * [1 - (sin(phi_n) * e/2) ^ 2] ^ 1/2 
R = r_eq * cos(phi_n) * (a + b) / c
```

Does anyone know what is going on here? I've been searching and reading about stereographic projections, but I wasn't able to find anything like that. In fact, I've not seen any projections that use this "null distortion coordinate."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two things are happening here.

**The first** is the replacement of the actual latitude phi_n by the ["conformal latitude"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude#Conformal_latitude) phi_nc.  Think of this as distorting the ellipsoid (as specified by r_eq and e) into a perfect sphere.  Because it is an ellipsoid of revolution, no change to the longitude occurs (lambda_n = lambda_nc), but the latitudes shift slightly.  They do so in a way that is locally angle-preserving ("conformal").

**The second** is a slight adjustment of the [scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Scale) of the stereographic projection, also to account for the shape of the ellipsoid.  This is reflected in the variable *c*, which you can see depends on the eccentricity *e* (the sole determiner of the ellipsoid's shape).

Here is John Snyder's account:

> ...the ellipsoidal forms of the Stereographic projection are nonperspective, in order to preserve conformality.  The oblique and equatorial aspects are also slightly nonazimuthal for the same reason.  **The formulas result from replacing geodetic latitude *phi* in the spherical equations with conformal latitude *chi* ... followed by a small adjustment to the scale at the center of projection.**

[Map Projections--A Working Manual](http://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395), p. 160, emphasis added.

---

Incidentally, "null distortion coordinate" is an idiosyncratic term.  According to Google, this thread is the *only* place on the Internet where such a phrase occurs!

Comment: Thanks whuber. So, if I correctly understand, the factors that multiply r_eq are a math to calculate the scale factor (Ko)?
The term "null distortion" is a translation (in the code I'm using, the variable names are in portuguese). Maybe somewhere else it does have a different name.

Comment: @Alexandre (1) The correction is more than a constant scale factor: notice how it varies with latitude.  (2) "Null distortion" is too vague, because [variations on the same theme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude#Auxiliary_latitudes), such as *authalic latitude,* are used to control metric distortion in other kinds of projections of the ellipsoid.  Therefore I doubt that the original Portuguese is a standard term, either.

Comment: Also, in our code the R variable is called "conformal radius".

Comment: After a long search, I've found the description of this specific projection. It's used by radar systems, and the document can be found on http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?Location=U2&doc=GetTRDoc.pdf&AD=AD0771544

Comment: @Alex Thanks.  That document indeed uses the terms "conformal latitude" and "conformal longitude."